# PHP Select an Item from a Combo box and set an input field with the value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php program I am working on which has categories and sub-categories.
What I have done is select with DISTINCT all categories and sub-categories.
I then have a form which I would like to select a know category or ADD a new one.

Here is my code at the moment but does not work, any thoughts..
I am a newbee with php.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function mySubFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("subcat");
    var y = document.getElementById("isubcat");
    if (x.selectedIndex >= 0) {
        var sel = x.options[x.selectedIndex];  
        y.text = sel;
    }
}
</script>

    <div class="w3-input-group">      
        <label class="w3-label w3-text-brown"><b>Item Sub-Category</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-sand" id="isubcat" name="isubcat" type="text" value="<?php echo $isubcat; ?>">
        <select id="subcat"  onclick="mySubFunction()">
<?php
    foreach ( $results['subcats'] as $cats ) {
        if ($cats === $isubcat){
            echo '<option value="' .$cats['subcat'] .'" selected >' .$cats['subcat'] .'</option>' . "\n";
        } else {
            echo '<option value="' .$cats['subcat'] .'" >' .$cats['subcat'] .'</option>' . "\n";
        } // end if Sub-Category Items
    } // end foreach
?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not working means what? You see any error?

Comment: The value in the input field is not updated from the selected Combobox selection.

Comment: I think you want `y.value = sel;` instead of `y.text = sel;`

Comment: Still no response (as in change of value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this change (you are calling onclick event instead of onselect)

```
<select id="subcat"  onchange="mySubFunction()">
```

And change this part :

```
y.value = sel.text;
```

Note : use sel.value instead of you want to show option value instead of option text.

Comment: Still no response. Maybe my javascript is wrong. I am a new one at php and java.

Comment: Yep changed but got this. [object HTMLOptionElement]

Comment: Great, now just change the last part of your function (see my last edit). Hope this works. :)

Comment: @sippytom also need to add `.value` to `x.options[x.selectedIndex];` -> `var sel = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;`. With out the `.value`, you are getting the DOM object, ie. ` [object HTMLOptionElement] `.  see http://jsfiddle.net/pfm80drz/

Comment: @sippytom pls accept the answer if issue is resolved.